# onPressed didn't work with Animated Button

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I tried to make a Flutter animated circular fab menu with a fixed button and two animated buttons. The `onPressed` Method works only the fixed Button and didn't work with the fixed Button. I tried a lot of thing with iconbutton but always the same result.

This is a part of my code to explain the ui that I made. It has only three button one fixed button and the two animated buttons. The animation works correctly but the `onPressed` didn't work.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(),
        body: Container(

          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                  right: 30,
                  bottom: 30,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Transform.translate(
                        offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                            degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                        child: Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                              getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                            ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child:Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(color:Colors.green,shape: BoxShape.circle),

                            child:FloatingActionButton(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.stay_primary_portrait,
                                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              onPressed:(){something;
                              print("hi");},

                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      Transform.translate(
                        offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(180),
                            degThreeTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                        child: Transform(
                          transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                              getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                            ..scale(degThreeTranslationAnimation.value),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child:FloatingActionButton(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.stay_primary_portrait,
                                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              onPressed:(){
                              print("hi");},

                            ),,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Transform(
                        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                            getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,

                        child:Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color:Colors.red,shape: BoxShape.circle),

                          child:IconButton(

                            color: Colors.red,
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.menu,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                                animationController.reverse();
                              } else {
                                animationController.forward();
                              }
                              print('ok');
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
  void something(){
    print("hello");
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to edit your question to make it easier to read, but I need your help with the second sentence. "The `onPressed` Method works only the fixed Button and didn't work with the fixed Button" - did that mean to say The `onPressed` Method works only the fixed Button and didn't work with the animated Button"?

Comment: yes it's a mistake thank you